# cannot share table no matching primary key

Tags: asp.net

The entity types **'Profile' and 'Country' cannot share table 'Countries'** because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.

Answer (score 0):

try removing

```
public int? CountryID { get; set; }
```

from UserProfile so it looks like this:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public Country()
    {
        Profiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }


    public ICollection<UserProfile> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

another thing : you had `ICollection<Profile>` instead of `ICollection<UserProfile>`